# React native : apps crashed after try to uninstall react-native-firebase and gcm

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

i use reactnative to build my apps..and want to make notification for apps
React native : 0.52.0

then i want to try google cloud messanging. but i got some error and apps crashed. so, i try to redo all. i disable using //,  react-native-firebase, i also disable classpath com.google.gms.google-services
because before that, my apps actually dont use that service.

after i comment all, i try to build again , and i got error, i also already try to gradlew clean, but still same error :

```
2021-03-20 11:03:27.005 14894-14894/com.albums E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.albums, PID: 14894
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.evernote.android.job.gcm.PlatformGcmService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.evernote.android.job.gcm.PlatformGcmService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.albums-ieya-j2-1Zn9pFP9odyFew==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.albums-ieya-j2-1Zn9pFP9odyFew==/lib/x86, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.albums-ieya-j2-1Zn9pFP9odyFew==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3324)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1677)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.evernote.android.job.gcm.PlatformGcmService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.albums-ieya-j2-1Zn9pFP9odyFew==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.albums-ieya-j2-1Zn9pFP9odyFew==/lib/x86, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.albums-ieya-j2-1Zn9pFP9odyFew==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3321)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1677) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmTaskService;
    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
            ... 10 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmTaskService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.albums-ieya-j2-1Zn9pFP9odyFew==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.albums-ieya-j2-1Zn9pFP9odyFew==/lib/x86, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.albums-ieya-j2-1Zn9pFP9odyFew==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

somebody can help me what the problem was ?
Thank you for your help